# can't exclude UIActivityTypePostToFacebook from [UIActivityViewController excludedActivityTypes]

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller

I wish to create a `UIActivityViewController` which will exclude some of the native share features including Facebook and Twitter Share. But the Facebook share is still available as a `ShareExtention`.

I create the following :

```
activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems  applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
```

and excluded Facebook by setting the excluded Activity types.

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[
                                                 UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                 UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                 UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                 UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                                 UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                                 UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                                 UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                                 UIActivityTypePostToTwitter
                                                 ];
```

When running on my iPhone the Facebook icon appears despite being excluded.

Investigating how this is happening I see that the completion handler for the activity controller is returning the `activityType = com.facebook.Facebook.ShareExtension`, not `UIActivityTypePostToFacebook`. Also when selecting the more button in the activity controller there is a toggle for Facebook as for other apps which make use of the Share convention.

Why is Facebook using the `shareExtention` when Twitter is not, and why can I not exclude it using the excluded activities?

Note: I have tested this on several devices but the issue only exists on one device which is running 8.1.3.

Thanks

Comment: having the same issue on iOS 8.1.1. Seems like it might be an apple-side bug.

Comment: It looks like you're seeing the Facebook share extension (which is part of Facebook iOS app). Do you have Facebook app installed (and which version)?

Comment: Yes, it is the Facebook share extension. I referenced this in my question actually. But the point is that if Facebook makes use of a share extension then it is not possible to disable Facebook sharing so :
excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, etc. is not usable.

Comment: I am running Facebook Version 30.0, updated on May 7th. (I allow auto update)

Comment: Does adding com.facebook.Facebook.ShareExtension to exludedActivityTypes help?

Comment: I have a similar situation in my app. Looks like on iOS 8.3 it is fixed and on iOS <= 8.2 it occurs. Still investigating but pretty sure @ilyashev is right it's an Apple bug.

Answer (score 5):

Try this way

```
// sharing items in an array lets say sharingItems
NSArray *sharingItems = @[@"hello", @"how", @"are", @"You."];

//making UIActivityViewController object lets say avc
UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];

//exclude UIActivityTypePostToFacebook 
avc.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook];

//presenting UIActivityViewController in our case avc
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

see the below picture, Facebook is not included

[image: In image Facebook not included]

When commenting  `avc.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook];` Facebook again becomes visible in share option

[image: When commenting avc.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]; Facebook again becomes visible in share option]

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hope this helps . This is how it is done in Swift 3.

  //  When Including the FB Option the code is as follow:

      func otherSharing() {

            let activityItem: [AnyObject] = [returnFinalImage() as AnyObject]


            let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItem as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)
             avc.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToTwitter]
            self.present(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    //When Excluding the FB Option the code is as follow:

        func otherSharing() {

            let activityItem: [AnyObject] = [returnFinalImage() as AnyObject]


            let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItem as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)
             avc.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.postToTwitter]
            self.present(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    //I have Added Screen shot : [![enter image description here][1]][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGzqC.jpg
```